# OnEdit Not Triggering With Copy & Paste in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a script that adds the current date when column one is edited, but at the moment it doesn't work when a value is **pasted in**.

Is it possible to make this script add the date for each row of the range that is pasted into column 1?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetName() == 'Add Statements Here' && e.range.getColumn() == 1) {
    e.range.offset(0,10).setValue(e.value.length>0 ? new Date() : '');
  }

}
```

Comment: is this google apps library?

Comment: It's in Google App Script on Gsheets :)

Comment: Are you sure the method is not getting triggered at all? Even outside the if?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When pasting onto the cell, the "value" property of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) is set to `undefined`.

Thus, evaluating `e.value.length>0` (as in line 3 of the provided code), results in a TypeError since `undefined` does not hold a "length" property.

In order to overcome this problem I suggest you use `e.range.getValue()` instead of `e.value`, since the range property will be declared whether you insert the value by manually typing it or pasting it.

Your modified code could look like below:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetName() == 'Add Statements Here' && e.range.getColumn() == 1) {
    e.range.offset(0,10).setValue(e.range.getValue().length>0 ? new Date() : '');
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is really weird behavior, but I think I have a rough idea of what's going on. The [event parameter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) for `onEdit()` provides the property `value`, but note the caveat that is the final sentence

> New cell value after the edit. *Only available if the edited range is a
>   single cell.*

It seems that if you paste *over* the cell, then Google handles the action as a potential batch operation and assumes the range is not a single cell, so `value` isn't returned. Consider that if you selected range `A1:D1` and pasted it *over* `A2`, that would modify cells `B2`, `C2`, & `D2` as well.

However, if you paste *into* cell `A2` (double-clicking into the cell before pasting), then the only cell modified is `A2`.

So the difference between pasting *over* and pasting *into* is basically the difference between using [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) and [`setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue).

To work around this, try removing or changing your ternary condition `e.value.length>0 ? new Date() : ''`

For example, the modified code below will check if the first value in the edited range has a length greater than zero, but if you paste multiple rows at once, it will only print the timestamp for the first row. This is easily resolved, if you need to do so, by adjusting your [`.offset()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer)) or using [`.getHeight()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getheight) (and potentially [`.getWidth()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getwidth)).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetName() == 'Add Statements Here' && e.range.getColumn() == 1) {
    e.range.offset(0,10,1,1).setValue(e.range.getValue().length>0 ? new Date() : '');
  }
}
```